# When we construct a regular sub manifold, can we set any coordinate of the coordinate system equal to 0?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

In the textbook "An Introduction to Manifolds" written by Loring W.Tu, I am confused about a proof of a theorem.
The theorem aims to prove that if $g:N \to \mathbb{R}$ is a smooth map on the manifold $N$ then, a nonempty regular level set $S = g^{-1}(c)$ is a regular sub manifold of a manifold of co-dimension 1.

In the proof, assume $f = g - c$, and assume $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^1}$ not equals to zero, then $(U_p,f,x^2,\dots,x^n)$ formed a coordinate system. And after we proved that there existed a neighborhood $U_p$ of $p$ on the level set $U_p \bigcap S$ is defined by setting the first coordinate f equal to zero. Then $S$ is a regular submanifold of dimension $n-1$ in $N$.

Here is the proof:
[image]
[image]

My question is that can we set other coordinates to be zero? If can't, why we must have to set $f$ equal to zero?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The difference of two smooth functions is still smooth, so we may always reduce to the case $c=0$

Comment: @leibnewtz Yes I know the reason we set $f = g - c$ then we can form the zero level set, I want to know when we construct the regular sub-manifold(assume we find a chart), can we set random coordinate of the coordinate system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can substitute $f$ for the $i^{\text{th}}$ coordinate $x^i$ precisely when $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}\ne 0$. This is what's required to insure that the Jacobian determinant is nonzero.

Comment: I know it is  required to insure that the Jacobian determinant is nonzero, I am confused about the definition of regular sub-manifold. In the textbook: "Relative to the chart $(U_p, f,x^2,...,x^n)$ the level set $Up \bigcup S$ is defined by setting the first coordinate f equal to 0". For example, can we set $x^2$ to be zero?

Comment: Sure. That has nothing to do with your submanifold; that will just give you literal linear hyperplanes.

Comment: Thank you! I got that.